# Upload and read a compressed file to populate a database

Tags: php

To populate an sql database I upload .txt files with all data for each field and rows. When my internet connection is bad i have a lot of problems and sometimes process is aborted.
To fix the problem I'd upload .txt files in a compressed format(.zip or if possible also other formats: .rar ...etc). In this way, filesize is 15 times smaller and i can upload it easier and faster.
How can i do?

Here are codes i use at the moment:

upload.php

```
  ...
  <form action="readfile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <br>Filename:&nbsp;<input name="userfile" type="file">
  <p><input type="reset" value="Reset">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>
  ...
```

readfile.php

```
  ...
  // Read data posted from form
$browser_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$temp_name = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$usrname = $_POST['uname'];

// Connect to the database
if (!($connection = @ mysql_connect ($hostName,
                    $username,
                    $password)))
    die ("Could not connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db ($databaseName, $connection))
    showerror();

echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\"\"http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd\">";
echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";
echo "<title>Upload file</title>";
echo "</head>";
echo "<body>";

// Was a file uploaded?
if (is_uploaded_file ($temp_name))
{
    echo "<h1>File Upload $browser_name</h1>";
    echo "<p>Filename - $browser_name\n";
    echo "<br>User name - $uname\n";

    // Open the file
    if (!($file = fopen ($temp_name, "r")))
        die ("Could not open the file $file\n");

    // Read the first line
    $string = fgets ($file, 1024);
  ...
```

Where to modify and/or add codes?
If you need more details, please ask me and I paste more: I presumed they're the right lines to explain better everything and to modify for my needs.

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Mattew

UPDATES:
I made some new modifies using ZipArchive. In a few words now the .zip file is uploaded in a folder and unzipped. So the nomefile.txt file can be read and processed as a normal .txt file inside the specific folder.
Unfortunately the fopen looks for a specific filename. My idea is now to rename any unzipped file (having a random name but .txt extension) to a specific file (for example myfile.txt). In this way i can fix also problems with "different" extensions having small/capitol letters such as .txt and .TXT

HERE IS THE CODE I MENTIONED BEFORE:
      ...

```
  //unzip del file
   $zip = new ZipArchive;
   $zip->open('file.zip');
   $zip->extractTo('./');
   $zip->close();
   echo "File unzipped and ready to be processed";



    if (!($file = fopen ("namefile.txt", "r")))
        die ("Could not open the file $file\n");

    // Read the first line
    $string = fgets ($file, 1024);
    ....
```

Opinions? Helps?
Thanks in advance, I'm very new of php and maybe my problems are elementary, excuse me.

Bye.

Comment: See PHP ZipArchive - http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

Comment: Treffynnon, your suggestion has been very useful! I made some modifies and it seems to work as i wanted, please read the question that i edited and updated. Bye!

Answer (score 2):

Use the ZIP Wrapper:

```
$filedata = file_get_contents("zip://absolutepathtozip.zip#pathintozip/file.txt");
```

Comment: I like this idea for just getting one file. I forgot about the zLib file stream wrapper. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php

Answer (score 1):

The approach differs with the compression mechanism you use, since the available libraries all use different interfaces; Exemplary, I'll show bzip2 here since that seems to be the simplest to me. Locally, just execute `bzip2 <file>` on any *ix command line shell; on Windows you could use e.g. 7-Zip for creating a .bz2 file.

In your php, you will want to read the whole file content instead of single lines (single lines don't make much sense in a compressed file). So you'll have to change your code starting from opening the files:

```
/*
// Open the file
if (!($file = fopen ($temp_name, "r")))
    die ("Could not open the file $file\n");

// Read the first line
$string = fgets ($file, 1024);
*/

$compressed_filecontent = file-get-contents($temp_name);
$filecontent = bzdecompress($compressed_filecontent);
...
// instead of reading from the file line by line,
// you'd then have to split up the $filecontent variable
// in separate lines and work on them
```

Note: of the ["compression" formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php) where there is a PHP library available for, only LZF is similarly simple to use (you'd just have to replace [bzdecompress](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bzdecompress.php) with [lzf-decompress](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.lzf-decompress.php)); that is because the other formats (like ZIP and RAR) are not only compression formats but also archiving formats (meaning that such files can hold multiple compressed files). That makes reading them a little harder - see the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I imagined to upload zip files and unzip them in a temporary directory where readfile.php can normally read and populate the database. Is it a worse approach?

Comment: If memory usage is a concern, if you're uploading big files, or if you want to upload more than one file at a time, yours is probably even the better idea.